# What is best Selenium tool to Automate tests?

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, automation

I have just started with Selenium to automate couple of tests and have found that there are couple of tools that I can choose from, like the Selenium IDE, Selenium WebDriver, Selenium RC, WebDriver Backed Selenium.
I have created the test cases on Selenium IDE and its easiest to create the test cases using it for a non developer.
Then I have exported them for C#/Nunit/Webdriver; But it seems I get lots of differences while translating from IDE to WebDriver.

Can anybody suggest if I am on the right track to go ahead or please suggest if otherwise.

If the suggestion is for WebDriver then should I just go with Selenium WebDriver for DotNet(as a C# developer) or I should choose WebDriver backed Selenium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother building tests using Selenium IDE, you will loose chance of building modular tests if you do so. If application changes in future, you will have to modify all your tests independently.

Your best bet is to use Selenium Webdriver with C# and also use some test framework like NUnit, so that non developers can run the tests using NUnit GUI using simple interface, that is the best approach I found so far.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Well, actually I am automating the tests - so the test fails will actually be reported automatically.I have some non-dev guys who will actually give me the test cases and based on that I am writing the automated tests.

Comment: But, as I stated earlier, if you develop tests using Selenium IDE, there will not be any modularity, you won't be having chance to build functions and reuse them etc. Selenium IDE also has problems of not being able to identify dialog boxes etc., so you better start with building a framework and develop tests directly in C#. If you do so, you can use concepts like PageObjects where you will get opportunity to maintain object locators at common place. However, you are the best judge for your situation so think thoroughly and decide otherwise, you will face problems in long run. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Just wondering is this you are suggesting for WebDriver for DotNet[http://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver] or its the WebDriver Backed Selenium[http://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium] ? I assume the two have some differences.

Comment: WebDriverBackedSelenium is a stop gap arrangement for people who already have selenium scripts. However if you are at beginning phases of your project, I suggest you go with WebDriver, you will have much stronger community support on that as well as WebDriver has better future forecast.  Check this link... https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/selenium-developers/vFD0KVGoarg

Answer (score 1):

Selenium IDE is still useful for rapidity. In Selenium IDE, click,record and save the test script then still in Selenium IDE, export it to your favored language, e.g. python or nodeJS, etc then open the exported selenium IDE code in the editor of that webdriver language format, run the test again then fix the inevitable errors you see.e.g. for every ,say 20 lines of  selenium IDE code you exported to, say python, you will see, say, 5 lines of code that will need to be fixed, but it still saves time specially for beginner automators.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it makes sense to recommend java to a c# developer:D
If you want to use selenium and c# I suggest you check LightBDD framework (really brilliant but needs you to be skilled at c# itself) and combine that with PageObject approach.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use *Webdriver* is with *Java*.

You can choose *Java* for writing tests, *TestNG* for test framework and *Maven* to build your test *Jars* making it machine independent. *Maven* will packaeg all your stuff into one *Zip* file.

But since you are begineer, choose webdriver for your automation. It can be used with either *Java* or *C#*.

Comment: I think the question was for C# :)